# One word Substitute

Tags: single-word-requests

One word substitute for someone who remembers his/her friend only when he/she is in trouble and ignores them rest of the time.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is [Opportunist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/opportunist).

a person who adapts his actions, responses, etc, to take advantage of opportunities, circumstances, etc